# position fixed div overlap

Tags: html, css

I have a two divs like this:

```
<div style="position:fixed;height:100px;top:0;left:0;right:0;z-index:999;">
   // some fixed content here...
</div>

<div>
    // some other content here...
</div>
```

As you can see, the first div has position fixed. The problem I have is that the second div is overlapping with the first div. Any idea how I can fix this while keeping my first div `fixed` please without putting some kind of padding top to the second div or something?

Thank you

Comment: Why are you adverse to padding-top?  Is `position: fixed` the correct option if you don't want it to overlap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the margin-top of the second div to something greater than 100px. This way it will appear right below the first div